# How to import SpatiaLite data into GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, spatialite, import

How can I import SpatiaLite tables into GRASS? Are there any restrictions I should be aware of? How does GRASS cope with columns that don't have a specific type (Sqlite tends to create such columns e.g. if you create a new table from a query using SUM() or similar)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

http://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/sql.html

http://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/grass-sqlite.html

Helpful: "The result is a mixed bag."
http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Spatial_SQL#SQLite

Comment: Do you have personal experience using spatialite with grass?